# jQuery (and others) event handler wrapper conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jquery-events

**UPDATED AT THE BOTTOM**

***ORIGINAL***

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXx6d/) that shows my problem. I will describe the problem in a moment. This is the code, since SO wants me to paste it:

**HTML**

```html
<input class="on" value="on" type="button" />
<input class="off" value="off" type="button" />
<div class="subject"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
(function($) {
    var wrap = function(func) {
        return function(e) {
            console.log('click some special logic');
            func.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments,0));
        };
    };
    
    function generic_click_func(e) {
        console.log('generic click called');
    };
    
    function generic_mouseover_func(e) {
        console.log('generic mouseover called');
    };
    
    function generic_mouseout_func(e) {
        console.log('generic mouseout called');
    };
    
    $('.on').on('click', function() {
        $('.subject').on('click', wrap(generic_click_func))
            .on('mouseover', wrap(generic_mouseover_func))
            .on('mouseout', wrap(generic_mouseout_func));
    });
    $('.off').on('click', function() {
        $('.subject').off('click', wrap(generic_click_func))
            .off('mouseover', wrap(generic_mouseover_func))
            .off('mouseout', wrap(generic_mouseout_func));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```css
.subject { height:20px; width:20px; background-color:#ff0000; }
```

**ISSUE**

The problem with my code is that when `wrap()` is called, even with the same `func` param, the resulting function is a new version of the function. Thus when compared to a previous resulting function with the same `func` param, it is not equal. The jsfiddle demonstrates this.

In the fiddle, we call `wrap(somefunction)` in two places, once for `.on()` and once for `.off()`, yet the resulting function of each call is considered a different function when compared to the other. This is techinically correct, because the `wrap()` function returns a *new function* each time it is called. Thus when calling the `.on()` function with this `wrap(somefunction)` param, and then later calling `.off()` with the same param (not the same i know), the `.off()` function does not find the function in the list (because of the method of comparison), and thus the handler is not removed.

I understand that if I was in control of the function comparison code, I could do something like this:

```js
if (''+func1 == ''+func2) { remove_handler(ele, func2); };
```

But alas, I am not, because this is part of jQuery. Specifically, it is part of the `inArray()` function, since that is what jQuery uses to remove event handlers, which is again correct, because `inArray()` has a multipurpose, where string comparisons are not always needed.

**WHAT I NEED**

I need a workaround for this problem, such that I can have a wrapping function like `wrap` that returns a wrapper of the `func` param, which can later be compared to another wrapped function that was created using the exact same code, and be equal according to jQuery, so that the `.off()` function can actually remove it. The jsfiddle is an exact example of what is going on. What I need is for the `.off()` functions to actually work, while maintaining the wrapper function sequence.

SIDE NOTE: in the example code I added `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to simply demonstrate that this wrapper function is a multipurpose, completely reusable piece of code, that is not exclusive to the `click` event. For that matter, it is not exclusive to a single element. It needs to work for multiple elements on the page, and multiple events for each element.

***UPDATE***

After an insightful comment from Andrew, I got this to work by simply taking advantage of the jQuery namespacing ability. This solves the problem for jQuery events; however, I have the exact same problem with the RaphaelJS `.click()` and `.unclick()` functions. Can anyone offer help with that? Here is a [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loushou/rXx6d/1/) that demonstrates the same problem using RaphaelJS.

Comment: Is namespacing the events and removing the namespaced events later an option? That way you could avoid the problem all together.

Comment: wow! excellent idea! let me give it a shot. i had not thought to look at it from another angle, lol. brb

Comment: ok. that works. however let me update the issue with a second part. this works for jQuery events, however now i need it to work with RaphaelJS events. sec

Comment: ok i added the raphaeljs issue, and a jsfiddle with the raphaeljs code, demonstrating the same problem with raphaeljs